# filter pandas dataframe by a list that includes an empty values

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

I have a dataframe and I need to create another dataframe that will include only records that are missing on a particular column.

'Missing' means it can be empty, 'N/A', 'NODATA' or in some cases other fixed values (I need a function so I can simply pass a list that fits the case).

I can filter it by the values, so the N/As and NODATA records are found, but it doesn't see the empty ones.

I tried multiple approaches, is it possible to do that in that way (so an empty value is a part of the list), or do I need to filter empty separately and merge it to the list-ones?

```
def GetEmpty(df, on, items_list=['']):
    column = df[on]
    boolean_series = column.isin(items_list)
    empty_df = df[boolean_series]
    return empty_df

empty_df = GetEmpty(df, 'Isin', ['','N/A', 'NODATA'])
```

Edit: the dataframe:

```
 System Book    Isin ID
0    ABC  DEF     XYZ  A
1    ABC  DEF     NaN  B
2    ABC  DEF     ABC  C
3    ABC  DEF  NODATA  D
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to check if it's empty (ie: Python's None or Numpy.NaN) AND check if it's one of these special values - the empty string (""), "N/A", or "NODATA".

Pandas has a build-in function called [isnull()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) which checks for None or np.NaN.

So, you could do something like this...

```
import pandas as pd

def GetEmpty(df, on, items_list=['']):
        boolean_series = df.apply(lambda x: True if ((pd.isnull(x[on])) or (x[on] in items_list)) else False, axis=1)
        empty_df = df[boolean_series]
        return empty_df
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you. So there is now way to include None or NaN as a part of the list and check vs this list?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you write "x[on] in [np.nan, "NODATA]", it won't return true if x[on] is "np.nan". It's just not comparable like that. You could add flags to your method like check_nan=True and test them separately if you need more flexibility.

The most supported way to check for np.nan is to use numpy.isnan() or pandas.isnull().

Comment: works perfectly fine and I understand everything, thank you